# Python - Sorting positive and negative numbers in one dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, numbers

I would like to ask you how exactly can I sort keys (integers) in dictionary in "ascending order" , including both positive and negative numbers.

I have this list of sorted numbers (sorted with code below):

```
01.Key: 06
02.Key: 07
03.Key: 21
04.Key: 59
05.Key: -26
06.Key: -17
07.Key: -7
08.Key: -6
```

But what I would like to have in output is this sorted list:

```
01.Key: 06
02.Key: 07
03.Key: 21
04.Key: 59
05.Key: -6
06.Key: -7
07.Key: -17
08.Key: -26
```

Currently I'm using this code to sort those numbers in ascending order (at least for positive numbers):

```
sorted_html_output_dict = sorted(html_output_dict.items(), key=lambda x: (x[0] < 0, x), reverse=False)
```

Is there any nifty way of doing this using lambda function or so?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I'm confused about the output you want. You said you want a list... does the list consist of strings like "<some key>: <some value>"? What determines which key goes with what value? (Are the keys sorted lexicographically?) Similarly, the input is strange... can you paste in an actual `dict` instead of colon-separated key/value pairs? (And if the values are numbers, why are there sometimes leading zeros? Are the values actually strings?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there.

Simply make the second item in the sort tuple the absolute value using `abs`. The negative come after the positive ones and they are sorted in a descending (ascending in an absolute sense) order:

```
sorted(html_output_dict.items(), key=lambda x: (x[0] < 0, abs(x[0])))
```

---

Sample:

```
>>> sorted([2, 1, 3, -4, -2,-6], key=lambda x: (x<0, abs(x)))
[1, 2, 3, -2, -4, -6]
```

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for! I thought about using absolute function for this to work, but forgot to try it out. Thanks a lot @Moses !

Comment: Are you sure this is what you wanted? It doesn't match the output in your question. (This code will keep 05.Key with -26, while your output has 05.Key paired with -6. Maybe your sample output was just wrong?)

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions I made:

1. The leading zeros are just typos of some sort, and the values are in fact numeric.
2. You want a new `dict` as output, not a `list`. (The output you described looked similar in form to the input, and you seem to have a `dict` as input.)
3. You want to sort the keys lexicographically to form the key/value pairs for the output dictionary.

Given those assumptions, I think this code does what you want. The values are sorted similarly to what you were already doing (though you were missing an `abs`). The keys are sorted lexicographically, and then the two are combined to form a new `dict`:

```
import pprint

d = {
    "01.Key": 6,
    "02.Key": 7,
    "03.Key": 21,
    "04.Key": 59,
    "05.Key": -26,
    "06.Key": -17,
    "07.Key": -7,
    "08.Key": -6,
}

d_sorted = {
    k:v for k, v in zip(
        sorted(d.keys()),
        sorted(d.values(), 
            key=lambda x: (x < 0, abs(x))
        )
    )
}

pprint.pprint(d_sorted)

# Output:
# {'01.Key': 6,
#  '02.Key': 7,
#  '03.Key': 21,
#  '04.Key': 59,
#  '05.Key': -6,
#  '06.Key': -7,
#  '07.Key': -17,
#  '08.Key': -26}
```

Comment: This is also a correct answer. Thank you very much! All I needed was this function:


`lambda x: (x < 0, abs(x))`


and sorry for confusing formatting in my original post. "01. Key:" is not an actual content/key of the dictionary, it is just being printed out in console to display all of the dictionary keys (and how many of them is there). 06, 07, 21... are keys and each of they key is pointing at its own html code (value).